# Selenium commands get slower with Dns Round Robin

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, httprequest

I'm using selenium webdriver in a project that process html documents, which works very well when in tha base project. However, it appears that when I set enableDnsRoundRobin to true, the command sent to the webdriver are slower (page loading, script execution).
This is one part of the problem that doesn't count much : I just have to put enableDnsRoundRobin to false.

The real problem is that I use that project as a DLL in another solution (in which I disabled enableDnsRoundRobin) and the selenium command are slower, whether I allow DnsRoundRobin or not (in fact, the command take the exact same time with or without enableDnsRoundRobin)...

Why does this setting change everything in my first program while it changes nothing in my second ?

Can anybody tell me what could cause that ?

(I also disabled expect100continue which, I heard, can slow down requests.)

EDIT: Oh ! And, I checked : These properties are not changed anywhere else in the solution...

**EDIT:** I have to use FirefoxDriver, but ChromeDriver doesn't have that problem, if that can help.

Comment: `enableDnsRoundRobin` is set where? It's not a Selenium setting.

Comment: @Arran, yeah, it's set either in the App.config  `<system.net>  <settings>  <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" dnsRefreshTimeout="30000" enableDnsRoundRobin="false" />  </settings>  </system.net>`)  or in the code using :  `System.Net.ServicePointManager.EnableDnsRoundRobin = false;`.